# Getting Memory Exception Error when calling C++ method from C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have C++ dll which has below method signature. I would like to know what should be compatible C# method to call C++ dll. I am getting error on execution as attempted to read write protected memory. The dll used here is third party dll. I am able to call simple methods without pointers from C++ dll.

**C++ Declaration:**

```
int __stdcall Deduct(int V, unsigned char *AI);
```

**C# Declaration**

```
 [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("rwl.dll",EntryPoint = "_Deduct@8", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]   
 public static extern long Deduct(long i,ref string AI);
```

As per the document of third party dll.

**AI** Used as input and output buffer. The buffer shall have at least 80 bytes
Input Additional Information for the transaction. It is a byte pointer containing 7 bytes.

e.g. Assume the usage information is not used,

```
if receipt number = 1234567,
hex value = 0x12D687,
7 bytes AI = D6 87 00 00 00 D6 87
Output On return, the AI contains the UD.
```

Please help.

Comment: I guess the C function manipulates the contents in `AI`, not just read.

Comment: CallingConvention is wrong, must be Stdcall.  EntryPoint is unnecessary, used only to work around the 1st bug.  Return type is wrong, must be int.  1st parameter type is wrong, must be int.  Second parameter declaration is wrong, must not be ref.   Second parameter type is wrong, string is immutable so must be StringBuilder with the Capacity set high enough to allow the native code to return a larger string.  High odds that it should be byte[].  The function is very unsafe since it doesn't know the buffer size and can easily corrupt the heap, a 3rd parameter is needed to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the c# signature looks wrong.

```
 [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("rwl.dll",EntryPoint = "_Deduct@8", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]   
 public static extern long Deduct(int i,ref char[] AI);
```

if it is expecting a char[80] as it's input you may need to declare it as such and null terminate it yourself as whatever is reading from it might be reading past the end of the array.

usage

```
char[] tmp = new char[80];
tmp[0] = (char)0x00;
int i = 0;
Deduct(i, ref tmp);
```

I'm not sure if this will work but hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Besides string marshaling, I found a likely reason for getting an exception.

You have specified the return type and the first parameter as `int` in C, but `long` int C#. This could cause problems.

C language specifies minimum bits of integer types which means that different for environments.

- `int` in C : unsigned integer, **at least** 16 bits
- `long` in C : unsigned integer, **at least** 32 bits
- `int` in C# : 32-bit unsigned integer, always
- `long` in C# : 64-bit unsigned integer, always

Most of major 32/64-bit OS/compilers use 32 bits for type `int` in C. However `long` is always 64-bit in C#. So the signature mismatches. I would suggest to revise:

```cs
public static extern int Deduct(int i, ref string AI); // Still not sure about string
```